# Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component. in App (created by withDevTools(App))

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a native react app. And I have this simple objects:

```
export const AnimalGroupScreen = () => (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.search}>
            <Searchbar />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.list}>
            <AnimalGroupInfo />
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
);
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

export const AnimalGroupInfo = () => <Text> Hello there</Text>;
```

and app:

```
import { AnimalGroupScreen } from "./src/features/animalGroup/screens/animal-group-screen";
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import ExpoStatusBar from "expo-status-bar/build/ExpoStatusBar";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <AnimalGroupScreen />;
            <ExpoStatusBar style="auto" />
        </>
    );
}
```

But I still get this error:

```
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

This error is located at:
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
```

And of course I searched for this error. But I only have a Text tag in the Info component.

And that seems correct. So how to tackle this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semicolon here:

```
<AnimalGroupScreen />;
```

Remove it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

remove ; from `<AnimalGroupScreen />;`

Comment: ahhh, oke. Thank you!! Yes, that was the trick. Thank you